# How can I get Sync Framework to compare a second folder for a one-way file sync?

Tags: synchronization, microsoft-sync-framework

I'm duplicating some SyncToy-like functionality for managing data replication. The goal is a **Contribute**-style sync, where CREATEs, CHANGEs, and RENAMEs on the "left" folder are replicated to the "right" folder, but not DELETEs.

Using the Sync Framework 2.1 SDK, I can successfully replicate **C:\FolderLeft** to **C:\FolderRight** and this is all good.

However, if I delete a file in **C:\FolderRight**, it isn't synchronized again on subsequent runs. (!!)

I realize this is due to Sync Framework keeping track that it already copied that file over once and it should be there, but we must design around a Chaos Monkey getting into **C:\FolderRight** and deleting stuff.

**So, how can I tell Sync Framework to verify, not assume, that a file is already sync'd?**

Current code for sync, mostly taken from MSDN code sample:

```
public void SyncFileSystemReplicasOneWay(
        string sourceReplicaRootPath, string destinationReplicaRootPath,
        FileSyncScopeFilter filter, FileSyncOptions options)
{
    FileSyncProvider sourceProvider = null;
    FileSyncProvider destinationProvider = null;

    try
    {
        // Instantiate source and destination providers, with a null filter (the filter
        // was specified in DetectChangesOnFileSystemReplica()), and options for both.
        Log("Initializing replicas from " + sourceReplicaRootPath + " to " + destinationReplicaRootPath);

        sourceProvider = new FileSyncProvider(
            sourceReplicaRootPath, filter, options);
        destinationProvider = new FileSyncProvider(
            destinationReplicaRootPath, filter, options);

        Log("Synchronizing changes from " + sourceProvider.RootDirectoryPath + " to replica: " +
            destinationProvider.RootDirectoryPath);

        // Register event handlers so that we can write information
        // to the console.
        destinationProvider.AppliedChange +=
            new EventHandler<AppliedChangeEventArgs>(OnAppliedChange);
        destinationProvider.SkippedChange +=
            new EventHandler<SkippedChangeEventArgs>(OnSkippedChange);

        // Use SyncCallbacks for conflicting items.
        SyncCallbacks destinationCallbacks = destinationProvider.DestinationCallbacks;
        destinationCallbacks.ItemConflicting += new EventHandler<ItemConflictingEventArgs>(OnItemConflicting);
        destinationCallbacks.ItemConstraint += new EventHandler<ItemConstraintEventArgs>(OnItemConstraint);

        SyncOrchestrator agent = new SyncOrchestrator();
        agent.LocalProvider = sourceProvider;
        agent.RemoteProvider = destinationProvider;
        agent.Direction = SyncDirectionOrder.Upload; // Upload changes from the source to the destination.


        agent.Synchronize();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log("EXCEPTION synchronizing from " + sourceProvider.RootDirectoryPath + " to " + destinationProvider.RootDirectoryPath + ": " + ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        // Release resources.
        if (sourceProvider != null) sourceProvider.Dispose();
        if (destinationProvider != null) destinationProvider.Dispose();
    }
}
```